# How to change header while switching 2 different modules in same Angular App

Tags: angular, routes, angular-ui-router

I have created the front-end(user side) and Admin side app in the same angular project. The project structure is attached in an image. The problem is that when I enter to the admin side, it works but the header remains the same as front-side.
[Main Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znesq.png)

[image: Admin Side structure]

these are my routing files, Please guide me to go through this process, I'm new to angular
[image: Main Routing Module code]

and this is admin routing file image

[image]

This is the User Side Header Code (index.html)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <base href="/">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <!-- The above 4 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->

  <!-- Title -->
  <title>Android App Ideas</title>

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="./assets/img/core-img/favicon.ico">

  <!-- Core Stylesheet -->
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/stylesheet">

  <!-- Responsive CSS -->
  <link href="./assets/css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico"> -->
</head>
<body>

  <app-root></app-root>

    <!-- jQuery-2.2.4 js -->
    <!-- <script src="../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> -->
    <script src="./assets/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Popper js -->
    <script src="./assets/js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap js -->
    <script src="./assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- All Plugins js -->
    <script src="./assets/js/plugins.js"></script>
    <!-- Active js -->
    <script src="./assets/js/active.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

And this is Admin Side Header (index.html)

```
  <!doctype html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <base href="/">
  <!-- Required meta tags-->
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="Admin Panel of android app ideas made with angular 7 by tayyab hayat">
  <meta name="author" content="Tayyab Hayat">
  <meta name="keywords" content="admin panel tayyab hayat android app ideas">

  <!-- Title Page-->
  <title>Dashboard</title>

  <!-- Fontfaces CSS-->
  <link href="./assets/css/font-face.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
  <link href="./assets/vendor/font-awesome-4.7/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
  <link href="./assets/vendor/font-awesome-5/css/fontawesome-all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
  <link href="./assets/vendor/mdi-font/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS-->
  <link href="./assets/vendor/bootstrap-4.1/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">

  <!-- Vendor CSS-->
  <link href="./assets/vendor/animsition/animsition.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
  <link href="./assets/vendor/bootstrap-progressbar/bootstrap-progressbar-3.3.4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
  <link href="./assets/vendor/wow/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
  <link href="./assets/vendor/css-hamburgers/hamburgers.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
  <link href="./assets/vendor/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
  <link href="./assets/vendor/select2/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
  <link href="./assets/vendor/perfect-scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">

  <!-- Main CSS-->
  <link href="./assets/css/theme.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/stylesheet">
    <!-- <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico"> -->
  </head>
  <body class="animsition">
    <app-root></app-root>

      <!-- Jquery JS-->
      <script src="./assets/vendor/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
      <!-- Bootstrap JS-->
      <script src="./assets/vendor/bootstrap-4.1/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="./assets/vendor/bootstrap-4.1/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <!-- Vendor JS       -->
      <script src="./assets/vendor/slick/slick.min.js">
      </script>
      <script src="./assets/vendor/wow/wow.min.js"></script>
      <script src="./assets/vendor/animsition/animsition.min.js"></script>
      <script src="./assets/vendor/bootstrap-progressbar/bootstrap-progressbar.min.js">
      </script>
      <script src="./assets/vendor/counter-up/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
      <script src="./assets/vendor/counter-up/jquery.counterup.min.js">
      </script>
      <script src="./assets/vendor/circle-progress/circle-progress.min.js"></script>
      <script src="./assets/vendor/perfect-scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.js"></script>
      <script src="./assets/vendor/chartjs/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
      <script src="./assets/vendor/select2/select2.min.js">
      </script>

      <!-- Main JS-->
      <script src="./assets/js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  </body>

  </html>
  <!-- end document-->
```

Comment: If I get it right you want a different header inside of your admin section than in your normal section? How big is the difference?

Comment: I'm new in Angular, and the method on youtube and on other helping websites are quite different. can you solve it on my code?

Comment: Have you created two different headers? If so, how do you use your admin header, please show us some code.

Comment: Yes, I've created 2 different headers with a different index page.

Comment: Question is Updated with Both admin and user side code